# HTML5 Angular website mixes up views from a separate website

Tags: angularjs, html, google-chrome, single-page-application

I have a very odd behaviour thing that is happening.  I have created 3 websites using Angular, HTML5 which talks to a WebApi.  The sites are different, hosted on different domains yet they have many identical components.

When switching between them, we often find that Chrome seems to get mixed up.  It will put the nav from the first site you visit into the nav of the second.  And other components too.  A simple F5 and the whole thing snaps back into line.

So, why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I think we have figured this one out.  The app calls the same news api with the identical call.  The only thing that differentiates the different websites is the basic authentication.  Chrome obviously ignores this when checking cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `"?nocache=" + Math.random()` to the request URL.